# Default locking for SQL Server 2005 - Row level or Page level

Tags: sql-server-2005, locking

Does SQL Server 2005 use row level locking or page level locking as a default?   I'm getting some timeout errors on some of my UPDATEs and wonder if it's related to the default locking mechanism.

Comment: http://churmura.com/technology/computer-science/sql-server-2005-lock-management/23976/

Comment: Thank you.  Great link.  I guess now I'm trying to figure out if my query is using row level locking or not.  It sounds like SQL Server 2005 determines which lock level to use based on different aspects of the query and usage?  I also need to look at isolation level and see what it's defaulting to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server always uses `row-level` locking by default

If you lock more than a certain amount of rows (5000), then `SQL Server` will do **[lock escalation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)** (lock the table instead of more than 5000 rows individually) to optimize performance and optimize on resource usage

My suggestion is to keep your transaction as short as possible..Or you can use with(NoLock) for those tables that are not being used for consecutive insertion by multiple users like Master Tables...

My another suggestion is to use SQL Profiler.

Comment: NOLOCK is only for queries for which correctness is unimportant!